# ML Kit Barcode Detector not recognizing ITF barcodes with 4 or less digits?

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

We are using the ML Kit Barcode Detector successfully in Android for a while now but noticed that the FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector doesn't seem to recognize ITF (Interleaved 2 of 5) barcodes with 2 or 4 digits (it works with 6 or more symbols). As far as I understand it ITF should work as long as the number of digits is even.

Is it possible to change this restriction or are there any plans to allow to change things like that (perhaps even per barcode type)?

I suppose the current implementation of having a minimum number of digits has performance reasons. However, we have customers that would like to scan barcodes which identify a specific rack before scanning articles; those barcodes usually contain only few digits.

[ITF barcodes with 4 digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nJI2.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will check with the team and get back to you. Do you have link to a sample image that I can pass on?

Comment: @PannagSanketi Sure, I've added a link with sample ITF barcodes.

Comment: Thanks. Passed it on to the team for debugging.